# REST API - Not Found Error

Tags: rest, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on a Rest Api for my application. This is my application structure

```
    api
    -config
    -modules
    --v1
    ---controllers
    ---models
    -runtime
    -tests
    -web

    backend
    common
    console
    environments
    frontend
```

I tried runing the following url http://192.168.1.4/~user/urshow/api/modules/v1/web/users

I got a Not found Error. I do have a controller named Users inside controllers folder.

My .htaccess file is like this (which is inside urshow/api/web)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~user/urshow/api/modules/v1/web/
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Try to create controller with name UserController

Comment: If you disable pretty urls, and remove the `.htaccess` file, does your site work and what do the urls look like?

Comment: still getting the same not found error @JoeMiller and i tried like this http://192.168.1.3/~user/urshow/api/web/movies/details

Comment: If you've disabled pretty urls then your urls should look something like this 192.168.1.3/index.php?r=movies/details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had made some mistakes. First my .htaccess file was incorrect.

i had this line before RewriteBase /~user/urshow/api/modules/web/

i changed it to RewriteBase /~user/urshow/api/web/

also the url which i was trying was also wrong http://192.168.1.4/~user/urshow/api/web/movies/details

correct url is http://192.168.1.4/~user/urshow/api/web/v1/movies/details.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the rest of the url to the redirect. Try using this on your last line;

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php$1
```

Comment: it didn't work still i have erorr The requested URL /~user/urshow/api/modules/v1/web/index.phpusers was not found on this server.